# Does Chewing Food Properly Ensure that we gain Less Fat?

Tags: digestion, fat-metabolism

We recently went to a fast-food corner and I was told by my sibling that even if we chew a burger properly(slowly) converting it into a fine bolus, then it would not affect the amount of fat gained by the body as much as we gain when we normally(hastily) eat a burger.

I ,on the other hand, don't believe in the above statements. I think that it will at least have a better impact with regards to weight loss.

So who ,among the two of us, is correct ?

Comment: the only result of chewing for a longer time is that the food on your plate will be colder at the end of your meal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding reasons for weight loss advice for slow eating/excessive chewing. Slow chewing is promoted because it [reduces apetite](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0195666311000547) not because slowly chewed food is digested differently. Slow chewing [reduces the objective amount of food people eat](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2212267213013750) before thay subjectively feel full. For standard sized meal it [reduces amount of snacks later](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/s0195666312004710).